# Python-ldap Add entry fails using Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework, python-ldap

I am trying to add an entry using python and calling that in a Robot TC. My python code is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ldap
import ldap.modlist as modlist
def LdapAddObject(l,dn,attributeDict):
attrs={}
for key in sorted(attributeDict.keys()):
    Attrib=getattr(attributeDict,key)
    attrs[key]=Attrib
    print attrs
ldif=modlist.addModlist(attrs)
l.add_s(dn,ldif)
l.unbind_s()
```

My Robot code is :

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     This testsuite checks the LDAP functionalities of DB nodes. 

*** Test Cases ***
Perform Ldap Operations
${ObjList}    Create List    subscriber
&{DN-Dict}    Create Dictionary    objectclass=${ObjList}    uid='2620105000000'
${ldapObj}    ldapopen    ${DB_1_EXT_APP_IP}
LdapAddObject    ${ldapObj}    uid=262010500,ds=hello,o=DEF,dc=LDB    ${DN-Dict}
```

It throws me an error saying :

```
TypeError: ('expected a string in the list', u'subscriber')
```

It is definitely failing somewhere within the add_s function.

Comment: Do you need the `for` loop in the python code - looks like it just transforms a dict to a dict?

Comment: It was just one of the trial and error that I tried. It isn't needed though.. It didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python-ldap used to have problems with Unicode strings - I haven't used it in a long time, not sure is it fixed in the latest versions.

Looking at the error, this looks like the case here though - just convert any unicode arguments to string, e.g. using the RF `Convert To String` or python's `str()`

Edit: for example, cast the list member:

```
 ${subscriber}     Convert To String    subscriber
 ${ObjList}    Create List    ${subs}
```

Similar for the dictionary values.

Comment: I have understood that objectclass expects a List as value. So i passed the same through Robot. But I suspect I haven't handled it well in python funtion.

Comment: @Arpitha what I mean is the list members and the dictionary values to be of String type (not Unicode); I've edited the answer to give an example.